# compareTo method for a linkedList?

Tags: java, testing, linked-list, comparable

Instructions:
[image]

My tests seem to be passing, but not sure if I am covering all the cases or possibility.

I feel my implementation is too simple. Can someone please examine?

My implementation:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(ListNoOrder<T> otherList){
    int sizeCompare = otherList.sizeOfList;

    if (this.sizeOfList > sizeCompare) {
        return 1;
    } 

    else if (this.sizeOfList < sizeCompare) {
        return -1;
    } 

    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: You just implemented the third check. But you return 1 in every case. One of the cases should return -1

Comment: This probably should go to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) IMO.

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 0):

You just compared the `size` of the `Lists`. Thats okay for the first step but when the `sizes` are identical you have to compare each `char`.